# Improper integral – Fourier transformation?

Tags: integration, fourier-analysis, improper-integrals

let us denote $$I(a,b)=\int_0^\infty t^{-3/2}\exp\left(\frac{-b(t-a)^2}{2a^2 t}\right)\mathrm{d}t\qquad\text{for }a,b>0.$$
I need to express $I(a,b)$ as a function of the two parametrs. According to Wolfram $I(1,2)=\sqrt{\pi}$. I think some pieces of spectral analysis may be useful here, but unfortunately I'm not familiar with this branch of maths.

So could you give me please an advice / a hint how to calculate the integral? Or on which part of Fourier analysis should I focus?

Thx.

Note: I don't want a solution, I'd like to resolve it on my own.

Comment: Begin with substitution $s = \sqrt{a/t}$.

Comment: You may be interested in this [integral representation of the modified Bessel function](http://dlmf.nist.gov/10.32.E10)